# How to create a serial approval process?

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

I need to create an approval process that should be handled in a serial manner.

The criteria is based on the sale amount (and not on the discount - which I feel gives me the trouble here)

Step #1 - So, if the sales is < 15k - the sales person can approve it

Step #2 - If Sales is between 15 and 25 - First the sales person needs to approve it, and than the sales director. *that's the requested behavior.

Attached is the current steps I have, but for #3 - since it's marked as a unanimous approval, there is no preset order of the approvers.

[image]

How can I make that it will be performed in order?
first: sales person - and only if sales person approves, it will move to next approver: 
second: sales director

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing possibility of request directly going to 'Sales Director' if Opp amount > 15000 . Because as per process you've built, it will skip Sales person.

Here I'm just seeing possibility of two steps

> step 1 sales person approval

: For this criteria should be :

```
"All records should enter this step".  This should ensure sales person always approve first before records going to director
```

> Step 2 : Sales director should also approve

In this you can put criteria :

```
Opportunity amount > 15000
```

You've not mentioned if 3rd person(role) also need to approve if opp amount > 25000

only In that scenario: 
2nd step condition should be :

> Opportunity amount > 15000 and  Opportunity amount <  25000

But then there should 3rd step in which records will enter only  if Opportunity amount > 25000 and you've to put 3rd person as approver.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For best answer please see the link. http://simplysfdc.blogspot.in/2014/07/salesforce-serial-and-parallel-approval.html